# How can I enable Chrome/Chromium Unity integration?

Tags: unity, google-chrome, chromium

I installed Ubuntu yesterday on a new laptop. After downloading and installing Chrome, I realized that there is no experimental integration Gnome3/Unity flag in about:flags? I remember using the integration with Chrome on an older machine, is it by some mistake that I can't see it here or was it remove from the experimental features of Chrome?

I can still see double close/minimize/maximize buttons - one set from the window manager, the other from chrome.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to right click on the Chrome title bar and set "Use System Title Bar and Borders":

[image]

Comment: is there any update on this? all those features were removed from chrome.

Answer (score 6):

Google Chrome/Chromium Browser uses to manage appearance customization under Settings/Personal Stuff.

Write: [chrome://settings/personal](http://#) in order to enter this section and choose "**Hide System Title Bar and use compact borders**" as shown in this screenshot:

[image]

Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

Go to preferences and make sure you have `Use System Title Bar and Borders` checked:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Click the 'wrench' icon, and then select "Settings".  From Settings select "Personal Stuff" and click the radio button next to "Hide system title bar and use compact borders"

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to right click on the black space next to the tabs and un uncheck `use system title bar`?

Answer (score 0):

Unity integration is not experimental anymore. It should be already enabled in your browser.

Comment: It isn't... I can still see double close/minimize/maximize buttons - one set from the window manager, the other from chrome.

Comment: @Seiryuu Do you at least get the Unity quicklist for Chrome when you right-click its Launcher icon? (I have the window controls issue, as well...might just be a temporary bug that snuck through.)

Comment: The quicklist is there (new window, incognito window...)