# Ubuntu 12.04 Chrome

Tags: 12.04, gui, google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I enable Chrome/Chromium Unity integration?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65645/how-can-i-enable-chrome-chromium-unity-integration)

I hate this bar in the chrome.

[image]

I just upgrade from 10.04 LTS I was wondering if there is a way to remove this.

Thanks.