# Chrome has two sets of Close, Maximize, Minimize buttons

Tags: google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I enable Chrome/Chromium Unity integration?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65645/how-can-i-enable-chrome-chromium-unity-integration)

Why do I have two sets of `Close Minimize Maximize` controls in my Chrome window?  Please see the upper left corner of this window shot.  It's a waste of space.

[image]