# Can I display Chrome/Chromium tabs in the top panel?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, panel, fullscreen

Is it possible to display chrome/chromium tabs in the top panel of ubuntu 12.10?

Answer (score 0):

If your referring to the toolbar at the top of Unity then I don't believe there is a method to do this.

A better idea might be an auto hide feature for the toolbar in Gnome Shell.(http://www.webupd8.org/2011/11/autohide-top-bar-extension-finally.html)  Unity at the moment isn't very customizable beyond lenses and hacking/building from source yourself.

Gnome Shell on the other hand is very customizable and it is easy to do if you want to make your own and you know a little programming.

I am sure you already know about this, but you can always press F11(Fullscreen mode) and then move to the next tab with ctrl+(tab number) like ctrl + 1 for the first tab or ctrl + 2 for the second tab.  I suppose this would be nice if you are trying to get all the extra space outta of your screen.

Hope this helps.  I am personally working on some Unity plugins of my own and I will keep your question in mind.

Comment: Thanks for reply! Autohide feature isnt working for me in 12.10, but anyway, this not solve my problem directly. I hope this feature will be implemented from either ubuntu or google. It would be nice if tabs could touch the top edge of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

This is near the top of google without a real answer to what is asked, there is an option in the menu:

Go into the chrome menu and click settings. Under the settings tab, go to appearance and click "Use System Title Bar and Borders"

It's default behavior in Windows, not sure why it is different in Ubuntu.

Comment: He's asking to put the tabs in the top panel not the window, for that one it's here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/65645/how-can-i-enable-chrome-chromium-unity-integration

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using Kubuntu (KDE version of Ubuntu), I switched to kubuntu for the same specific reason, kubuntu is an official fork of ubuntu and new versions are released with ubuntu, almost all apps working on ubuntu work on kubuntu as well.

Answer (score 0):

If your aim is to maximize chrome, getting a broader screen, just right click on Chrome window and select "Use system title and borders" unchecked.